# how to target or select second active item of owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

```
<section class="carousel3">
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme carousel pt-5 pt-lg-0  mt-lg-4">
  <div class="item d-flex justify-content-center">
    <img src="images/slider3_1.svg" class="img_fluid special" alt="slider_image">
  </div>
  <div class="item d-flex justify-content-center">
    <img src="images/slider3_2.svg" class="img_fluid special" alt="slider_image">
  </div>
  <div class="item d-flex justify-content-center">
    <img src="images/slider3_3.svg" class="img_fluid special" alt="slider_image">
  </div>
  <div class="item d-flex justify-content-center">
    <img src="images/slider3_4.svg" class="img_fluid special" alt="slider_image">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm making a slider that the second item of that slider have bigger height or transform scale than the other,which means that every items of that slider when comes to that position of slider takes bigger height or transform
But the problem is that i'm not getting select or target that specific position or second active item of owl-carousel so i make some style on it.
I'm trying to select that one using nth-child but wont work
Below is the link of that design
https://www.figma.com/file/liAIfQ3m1BFueBroE52fbM/Frispes-Landing-Page?node-id=0%3A1

Comment: can you share the stylings of the transformed element?

Comment: .carousel .owl-item:not(.active)+.owl-item.active {
            width: 445px !important;
            margin-top: -220px;
            height: 660px;
        }

Comment: All the currently visible slides get the `active` class, so `.owl-item:not(.active) + .owl-item.active + .owl-item.active` should allow you to target the second one.

Comment: CBroe
Thankyou so much you have solved my problem